# Powershell List Already expired accounts (2Months)

Tags: powershell

I have a task where i need to query Active Directory to list accounts that have been expired in last two months.

Basically we have expired accounts that needs to be kept for 2 months before they are deleted/moved. I looked into Search-Adaccount which has -AccountExpired but it doesnt have timespan or no way to query the "Expiry Date".

Any help would be appricated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each of the objects returned by searched `Search-ADAccount -AccountExpired` has the properties `AccountExpirationDate` and `LastLogonDate`. This means the you can pipe the output into the `Where-Object` cmdlet and filter on those properties.

```
Search-ADAccount -AccountExpired | Where-Object {$_.AccountExpirationDate -ge ((Get-Date).AddDays(-60))}
```

Comment: This will list accounts that expires *more* than 60 days ago, not *within* the last 60 days

Comment: Edited to fix the typo.